What are the factors that affect the deorbit time of a spacecraft from LEO?
ISS needs regular orbit raising manoeuvres to keep it in LEO. Sometimes a spacecraft or an upper stage of a launch vehicle reenters the atmosphere. What factors cause spacecraft to fall back down to Earth?


What factors cause spacecraft to fall back down to Earth?

In short, it's aerodynamic drag. Factors that affect drag include spacecraft mass, spacecraft cross section, altitude, and date.
Acceleration due to aerodynamic drag is inversely proportional to mass ($a = \frac F m$). Given two spacecraft with all other factors being the same, it is the less massive craft that will fall faster.
While the ISS is very massive, those other factors, cross section in particular, are what makes the ISS have to reboost so often. Force due to aerodynamic drag is more or less proportional to the craft's cross sectional area to the wind: $F_D = \frac12 \rho\, C_D A$, where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid (the upper atmosphere in this case), $C_D$ is the coefficient of drag, and $A$ is the cross sectional area to the wind. The coefficient of drag ($C_D$) is more or less the same for all spacecraft. However, the ISS has huge solar arrays and thermal radiators, which makes the ISS have a huge cross sectional area.
Unlike Kerbal Space Program, the Earth's atmosphere doesn't end at 100 km above the surface. Altitude plays a big role in the density $\rho$. Instead of suddenly dropping to zero, density drops off exponentially with increasing altitude. The ISS orbits in the very thin thermosphere. If it orbited higher it would need far fewer reboosts. It doesn't orbit higher due to limitations of the US Space Shuttle Program and the Russian Soyuz vehicles.
Finally, there's date that is a factor. When the Sun is very active (like it is now), the incoming sunlight (including ultraviolet and gamma radiation) makes the upper atmosphere swell. The Earth's upper atmosphere shrinks when the Sun is calm. The ISS has needed and will continue to need more frequent reboosts until the Sun once again calms down. This variation of the Sun happens over a roughly eleven year long solar cycle. The Sun is close to solar maximum right now.

Fundamentally, spacecraft reenter the atmosphere because our atmosphere doesn't end suddenly, the pressure just gets lower and lower as your altitude gets higher.
At 100 km, there is so much drag that you'll slow down until your speed is below orbital speed, and reenter on the next orbit.
At 300 km, it takes a few years.
At 1000 km, it takes decades.
At 36,000 km, it takes basically forever.
This varies a bit: solar activity changes the pressure profile of our atmosphere: big CMEs can cause the atmosphere to swell up, causing more drag at higher altitudes.

"and reenter on the next orbit". Not challenging the statement at all just wondering if I understand it correctly as I am interested in the nuances of being classified as "in orbit". I'm guessing (might depend on the spacecraft) that if you reach orbital velocity at 100 km, then after completing one orbit you will have slowed and dropped below 100 km, but still above entry interface, and still with a perigee above the ground. Then sometime during the second orbit you will descend to entry interface, and shortly thereafter your perigee will be below ground, thus no longer in orbit.

@StevePemberton I think it's faster than that https://space.stackexchange.com/a/67196/12102

@Uhoh - possibly so. I was using the term entry interface loosely, I meant the altitude (which varies) where the atmosphere is thick enough to make it impossible to complete a single revolution without hitting the ground. But there doesn’t seem to be definitive information about what that altitude range is. NASA defines entry interface as 400,000 ft (122 km), at that altitude you start to get noticeable heating effects and a tiny amount of "Q". The Space Shuttle began transitioning from RCS to using aero surfaces for control at around 80 km. So I would think it's somewhere between the two.

@StevePemberton " if you reach orbital velocity at 100 km, then after completing one orbit you will have slowed and dropped below 100 km, but still above entry interface" I don't think there is such a thing as completing one orbit below 100 km, unless perhaps you are a 1000 kg sphere of tungsten or other high-mass/low-drag exception. I think reentry/descent and perhaps incineration happens in less than 90 minutes starting at 100 km.

@uhoh - there's nothing magic that happens at 100 km, that was a round number selected by the people who are mainly involved in validating aviation records (originally ballooning records). Personally I would put it at 120 km, some like Jonathan McDowell prefer 80 km (closer to von Kármán's original calculations). My comment to Hobbes was a narrower concept of perigee above the ground. If you are at orbital velocity at 100 km will you hit the ground before completing one revolution? Reentering spacecraft are not necessarily good examples because at 100 km they are below orbital velocity.

@StevePemberton not "magic" at 100 km, but somewhere between 100 and 80 km the lifetime of an orbit of a some canonical satellite (assume it's moving in a circle at Keplerian orbital velocity) becomes shorter than the period of the orbit. Then it's not really an orbit anymore. Separate from that, something unusual does happen around 100 km: Why does Earth's atmospheric density have a big "knee" around 100 km? Is there a good analytical approximation?

@StevePemberton see also When is/will be the symposium to revisit the Karman line and consider the "McDowell line"?

@uhoh - The May 23, 2017 question you linked is quite interesting. Although a May 12, 2017 question discusses a density knee that occurs between 80-90 km. Part of David Hammen's answer to that question states "While the 100 km mark is a bit arbitrary, that a perhaps fuzzy boundary does exist is not. You can certainly see that boundary in the graph of temperature in Russell Borogove's answer. His graph happens to show a marked temperature change at an altitude of 90 km. (Where this occurs varies, with time of year, latitude, and paper author.)"
